# Get current week data in sqlite3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, sqlite, datetime

I am trying to get current week records from the sqlite3 database or at least get all records that are between the current date and the next 7 days, I have done it via between method but it's not working properly, and it fetches records from the next years.

Code:

```py
self.con = sqlite3.connect('car dealership.db')
self.cursorObj = self.con.cursor()

date = datetime.now()
now = date.strftime(('%d-%m-%Y'))
self.bb = datetime.now() + timedelta(days=7) 
self.newbb_week = self.bb.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')

self.buying_checks_row_main_week = self.cursorObj.execute('SELECT sellername,  paymentdate,  paymentvalue, car FROM cars_buying_checks  WHERE paymentdate BETWEEN (?) AND (?)',(now, self.newbb_week))

self.buying_checks_row_main_week_output = self.cursorObj.fetchall()
```

Question: Is there a better method to get the current week records data from the sqlite3 database?

Comment: `BETWEEN` will do a lexicographic comparison of the strings, so it won't work properly with D-M-Y formats. If you flipped it to Y-M-D and added padding zeroes, it would.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo thank you very much it worked much better now after flipping the date, but it still has some problems, it's not fetching all the records, and its not fetching duplicated records.
how to add padding to select  data from DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are formatting your dates in `%d-%m-%Y` format, which will not work in a `BETWEEN` expression because it uses string comparison; for example the date `10-01-2999` would be between `09-01-2022` and `11-01-2022`. You need to format them as `%Y-%m-%d` for `BETWEEN` to work correctly.

If the dates in your table are not formatted as `%Y-%m-%d` then you will need to update the table to put them into that format, using something like:

```sql
UPDATE cars_buying_checks
SET paymentdate = SUBSTR(paymentdate, 7, 4) || '-' || SUBSTR(paymentdate, 4, 2) || '-' || SUBSTR(paymentdate, 1, 2)
```

Comment: thank you very much it worked much better now after flipping the date, not fetching all the records, and its not fetching duplicated records, I think it's due to not adding padding to select from the Db function how to add padding to select  data from DB

Comment: @asaadkittaneh can you add some sample data that shows the problem to your question? that will make it easier to figure out the solution